# how to make next button, prev button in html to scroll a lot of elements in div?(use jquery, javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

!i have picture.

```html
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li class="li"> Div 1</li>
        <li class="li"> Div  2</li>
        <li class="li"> Div  3</li>
        <li class="li"> Div  4</li>
        <li class="li"> Div 5</li>
        <li class="li"> Div 6</li>
        <li class="li"> Div 7 </li>
        <li class="li"> Div 8 </li>
        <li class="li"> Div 9</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

when I have more element, it makes full the div. 
How can I make a  next button and previous button , I want scroll some elements when I click a button next , its  show 5 or 6 elements next. and when I click the previous button it scroll some elements in previous session.
thanks!

Comment: Maybe something like this https://www.google.de/#q=paul+walker+movies ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using [swiper.js](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/) in my projects to achieve this.

You can get it as a standalone js version and as a JQuery plugin. 
It works well on mobile and touch devices.
Look at the [documentation](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/get-started/) or the [examples](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/demos/) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchors (an `<a>` element with an `id` attribute used as a named anchor).

Browsers scroll the page to the right anchor (`<a id="myanchor"></a>`) on the URL like  `http://mywebsite.com/foo.html#myanchor`

In the Javascript side you can jump to a specific anchor thanks to `document.location.hash = "#myanchor";` ([lecture](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Location)).

So, you can add anchors to the DOM and bind actions to the buttons to compute the right anchor name.
Here is an example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      ul li { height: 200px;}
      #slider aside {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="slider">
      <aside>
          <button class="prev">prev</button>
          <button class="next">next</button>
      </aside>
      <ul>
          <li class="li"><a id="1"></a> Div 1</li>
          <li class="li"><a id="2"></a> Div  2</li>
          <li class="li"><a id="3"></a> Div  3</li>
          <li class="li"><a id="4"></a> Div  4</li>
          <li class="li"><a id="5"></a> Div 5</li>
          <li class="li"><a id="6"></a> Div 6</li>
          <li class="li"><a id="7"></a> Div 7 </li>
          <li class="li"><a id="8"></a> Div 8 </li>
          <li class="li"><a id="9"></a> Div 9</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    var step = 2;
    var nbDiv = document.querySelectorAll('#slider ul > a').length

    var prevBtn = document.querySelector('#slider button.prev');
    prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function onPrev(event) {
        actualPosition = parseInt(document.location.hash.slice(1));
        if (isNaN(actualPosition))
            actualPosition = step;
        var newPosition = actualPosition - step;
        if (newPosition < 0)
            newPosition = 0;
        document.location.hash = '#' + newPosition;
    });

    var nextBtn = document.querySelector('#slider button.next');
    nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function onNext(event) {
        actualPosition = parseInt(document.location.hash.slice(1));
        if (isNaN(actualPosition))
            actualPosition = 0;
        var newPosition = actualPosition + step;
        if (newPosition > nbDiv)
            newPosition = nbDiv;
        document.location.hash = '#' + newPosition;
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Note that you can add the anchor dynamically in Javascript ([lecture](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/anchor)):

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('#slider > ul > li');
for (var i=0, li; li=lis[i]; i++)  {
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.name = i.toString();
    li.insertBefore(anchor, li.firstChild);
}
```